# How to put an array with or between items in mongodb projection query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoskin

I have a mongodb database which stores items in the following format:

```
{
"2013" : {
    "2" : {
        "1" : {
            "item1" : {
                "1" : {
                    "a_type" : 10,
                    "b_type" : 5,
                }
            },
            "item2" : {
                "v1" : {
                    "a_type" : 10,
                    "b_type" : 5,
                }
            },
        },
        "3" : {
            "item1" : {
                "1" : {
                    "a_type" : 10,
                    "b_type" : 5
                },
                "3" : {
                    "a_type" : 10,
                    "b_type" : 5
                }
            },
            "item2" : {
                "v1" : {
                    "a_type" : 10,
                    "b_type" : 5
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
"2014" : {
    "1" : {
        "5" : {
            "item1" : {
                "1" : {
                    "a_type" : 10,
                    "b_type" : 5
                }
            },
            "item2" : {
                "v2" : {
                    "a_type" : 10,
                    "b_type" : 5
                }
            },
        },     
    },
}
"_id" : ObjectId("53b82417a4b4939c27e300ed")
}
```

I want to get some specific item data in a specific date with my query. I can do it for one day or more with hard coding but I want to give it an array which will be filled automatically with the specific dates and item names but after more than one day of searching in stack and mongo docs I couldn't find anything. Please help me with this.
Query for getting one specific item and date is like this :

```
db.collection(collectionName).findOne({}, {'2013.2.1.item1': 1, '2014.1.5.item2': 1},  function(err, res});
```

Thanks

Comment: The structure is not helping you. MongoDB cannot "traverse" keys named like this without resorting to JavaScript evaluation, which is a considerably slower option. You'll need to change your schema here, but it would help to add some explanation of what all of these fields are supposed to represent.

Comment: Yes the structure is not that good but I cannot change it. I changed the labels for the project owner's sake but the first three layers are year, month and day and the deeper layers are for example some device's name, model number and number negative and positive comments about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine your array which contains your query items is:

```
 var query = ['2013.2.1', '2014.1.5'];
```

Because of your DB structure, you have to use MongoDB projection to extract the query items, so you should do something like this

```
var projectionObj = {};
for(var item in query) {
    projectionObj[item] = 1;
}
```

It will produce bellow object:

```
{
    '2013.2.1': 1,
    '2014.1.5': 1
}
```

Then you can pass it to MongoDB find function like this:

```
db.collection([collectionName]).find({}, projectionObj);
```

It will return exactly what you want.